# HTML5 Canvas memory leak on resize

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, memory-leaks

I am the main programmer of a javascript/canvas 2d based library. 
In order to give the possibility to cache some content, I've implemented a canvas based cache system. Each DisplayObject has its own canvas in order to cache his rendering.

The main problem here is that I've detected a memory leak on canvas resizing. 
I've wrote a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atlanthot/pqukyf1c/)** that illustrates the problem.

```
function draw()
{

    var canvas = document.getElementById("tomahawk");
    var context = null;

    canvas.width = parseInt(Math.random() * 800);
    canvas.height = parseInt(Math.random() * 600);

    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    context.fill();
    context.restore();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame = (function()
{

    return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||  //Chromium 
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||  //Webkit
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || //Mozilla Geko
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || //Opera Presto
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || //IE Trident?
            function(callback, element){ //Fallback function
                window.setTimeout(callback, parseInt(1000/60));                
            }

})();

draw();
```

Does someone have a clue ? Do you know why resizing a canvas at a high frequency is causing memory leaks ? The main problem there is that I can't afford to do it in another way and I need to find the answer or a hack in order to free the memory...

Comment: What makes you think you have a memory leak? I ran a couple of profiles with the Chrome debugger on your jsfiddle and didn't notice anything obvious.

Answer (score 0):

By keeping the browser busy by resizing the canvas in a tight loop you are at the same time possibly preventing GC (Garbage Collection) to do its job, removing those unreferenced memory allocations.

Give the browser some room to breath (an user on a mobile battery driven device will also appreciate this). If you constantly need to resize a canvas instead of reusing/sharing it, you should might consider to change the code pattern a little as this indicates a design flaw, not a browser one. My 2 cents..